# Good way of popping the least signifigant bit and returning the index?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am new to C++ and I'm trying to write a function that will pop the least significant bit and then return the index of that bit. Is there a way to do this without creating a temporary variable?

Right now I have a function for finding the index and one for popping the bit but I'd like to combine the two.

```
inline int LSB(uint64_t b) {
return int(_tzcnt_u64(b));
}

inline uint64_t popLSB(uint64_t b, int index) {
    return (b ^ (1ui64 << LSB(b)));
}
```

My only idea requires a temporary index variable which just feels bad.

```
int bestIdea(uint64_t *b) {
    int index = int(_tzcnt_u64(*b));
    *b ^= (1ui64 << index);
    return index;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? And if there is anything else not necessary or dumb about this code I'm happy to take suggestions, this is my first project and I'm not sure about pretty much any part.

Comment: Why does this feel bad to you? There's benefit in having an easy-to-read implementation. Any approach without a temporary would likely result in less readable code. If you're worried about performance: The compiler will likely do a good job at optimizing simple code like this.

Comment: Furthermore consider using references instead of pointers. If you go with `int bestIdea(uint64_t& b) { ... }` you shift the responsibility of checking for null to the caller, if null is a possibility at all instead of just assuming noone will ever think of passing null as parameter...

Comment: Thank you! I will change that because checking for null was something I was going to have the caller do anyways.

Comment: what is `bestIdea(0)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a temporary variable. However modern architectures are [superscalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor) and [out-of-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution) so to better adapt for them you should only use that for the return value and don't use it to clear the least significant bit to avoid an unnecessary [dependency chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Dependencies)

```
int popLsbAndReturnIndex(uint64_t *b) {
    int index = int(_tzcnt_u64(*b));
    *b &= *b - 1; // Not depend on the previous line
    return index;
}
```

Now we have better [instruction-level parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) and the 2 lines in the body can run in parallel

Of course some really smart compilers can recognize the pattern and compile your original code to the version without dependency, but no one can guarantee that

---

Some more recommendations:

- Use [`std::countr_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countr_zero) instead of `_tzcnt_u64` if you have C++20 or higher
- Use references instead of pointers

The result is like this

```
int bestIdea(uint64_t &b) {
    auto index = std::countr_zero(*b);
    b &= b - 1;
    return index;
}
```

Comment: I recommend using *neither* references *nor* pointers. Instead, **pass by value**. Since the input is a scalar, passing by value will never be less efficient, and may well be *more* efficient, depending on whether or not the compiler is able to fully inline it.

Comment: @CodyGray true, but in this case, b is not only an input, it's also an output...